# Handling multiple endorsement in hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I have an application where in I need multiple organisation to endorse. The chaincode works well when there is no endorsement policy specified. But when  I give a endorsement policy of AND('Org1.member', 'Org2.member'), the update made by the chaincode does not commit.

The chaincode is called using Java sdk. Following is the code snippet:

```
public String[] invoke1() throws Exception {

    HFClient client;
    Channel sdkChannel;
    String chaincode;
    String function;
    String args[];

    chaincode= config.getChaincode();
    args= config.getArgs();
    function= config.getFunction();


    client=  HFClient.createNewInstance();
    client.setCryptoSuite(CryptoSuite.Factory.getCryptoSuite());
    client.setUserContext(config.getUser());

    sdkChannel = client.newChannel(config.getChannel());
    sdkChannel.addPeer(client.newPeer(config.getPeer1Name(), config.getPeer1Url(), config.getPeer1Properties()));  //anchor peer Org1
    sdkChannel.addPeer(client.newPeer(config.getPeer2Name(), config.getPeer2Url(), config.getPeer2Properties()));  //anchor peer Org2
    sdkChannel.addOrderer(client.newOrderer(config.getOrdererName(), config.getOrdererUrl(), config.getOrdererProperties())); // orderer
    sdkChannel.initialize();

    final TransactionProposalRequest proposalRequest = client.newTransactionProposalRequest();
    final ChaincodeID chaincodeID = ChaincodeID.newBuilder()
            .setName(chaincode)
            .build();
    // chaincode name
    proposalRequest.setChaincodeID(chaincodeID);
    // chaincode function to execute
    proposalRequest.setFcn(function);
    // timeout
    proposalRequest.setProposalWaitTime(60000);
    // arguments for chaincode function
    proposalRequest.setArgs(args);

    System.out.println(proposalRequest.getChaincodeEndorsementPolicy());
    // Sending transaction proposal

    final Collection<ProposalResponse> responses = sdkChannel.sendTransactionProposal(proposalRequest, sdkChannel.getPeers());
    sdkChannel.sendTransaction(responses, client.getUserContext());
    String ret[]= new String[responses.size()];
    int i= 0;
    for (ProposalResponse resp : responses) {
        System.out.println(resp.getStatus());
        if (!resp.isVerified()
                || resp.getStatus() != ProposalResponse.Status.SUCCESS) {
            String str= "Error while executing chaincode from peer " + resp.getPeer().getName() + " status: "+ resp.getStatus() + ". Messages: " + resp.getMessage()+ ".";
            throw new RuntimeException(str);
        }
        else
            ret[i++]= new String(resp.getChaincodeActionResponsePayload());
    }
    System.out.println(sdkChannel.sendTransaction(responses));
    return ret;
}
```

The chaincode execution on both the anchor peer succeeds, however the changes made by the chaincode is not committing. 
Following is the peer log:
[image]

Can any one please help me out with this.

Comment: Are you sure transaction proposal reaches to all peers ? Also what logs you are getting at chaincode container `ccenv`  ?

Comment: yes the proposal is reaching all the peers. as you can see from the peer log, VSCC error is thrown as the signature set did not satisfy the endorsement policy.

Comment: Have you tried changing the endorsement policy to OR('Org1.member', 'Org2.member')? This might help in debugging if one of the transaction fails due to one of the peer.

Comment: Yes I tried with OR('Org1.member', 'Org2.member'). Its giving the same error

Comment: Can you please share your chaincode container logs ? Highly likely your chaincode login fails then !

Comment: Had you alredy verified the certificates? Its mapped correctlly? you can use " openssl x509 -in certificate.crt -text -noout " to decode the certs and verify if its ok.

Comment: Is there a possibility of chaincode login failure only if endorsement policy is specified. Yes certificates are mapped correctly. Every thing is working good if endorsement policy is not specified.